# What does this definition of a tangent vector mean?

Tags: derivatives, vectors, manifolds, definition

The tangent vector $\nu = \frac{d\lambda}{dt} \Bigr|_{\substack{p}}$ to a curve $\lambda(t) : R \to M$ at a point $p$ on a smooth manifold $M$ is the map from the set of real smooth functions $f$ defined in a neighborhood of $p$ to $R$, defined by

$\nu :f \to  \frac{d(f \circ \lambda)}{dt} \Bigr|_{\substack{p}}    $

My question is, why does one need the functions $f$?

Why not say the tangent vector is $\frac{d\lambda}{dt}\Bigr|_{\substack{p}}$ without reference to some functions on the manifold? What makes this argument naive/silly?

Is it because it simply cannot be defined this way? Why not use the coordinate system of the charts to map to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and use the homeomorphisms instead of $f$?

Also, sorry if this question is not a good one. I am a high school student, so I am self-learning this and I do not claim to be an expert. I  know I barely know anything.

Comment: $\frac{d \lambda}{dt}$, if it means anything at all, should mean $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\lambda(t + h) - \lambda(t)}{h}$. But $\lambda(t + h) - \lambda(t)$ has no meaning on a smooth manifold: you can't subtract two points. As you say in the comments to José's answer, you can force this expression to be meaningful by picking a chart, but then there's no reason for the answer you obtain using two different charts to agree.

Comment: So to do calculus on the manifold you need more structure on it(metric, connection)?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "do calculus." We can do calculus on any smooth manifold via differential forms; this is enough to get Stokes' theorem, for example.